# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips on Hover & Focus

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Twitter bootstrap tooltip trigger default is hover.

I can add data-trigger="focus" to cause the tooltip to display on focus, but how I do both hover and focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution by @Adrian does not work on Bootstrap 3. Use following:

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
$(document).on('hover', '[rel=tooltip]', function () { $(this).tooltip('show'); });
$(document).on('focus', '[rel=tooltip]', function () { $(this).tooltip('show'); });
```

Answer (score 7):

have you tried `data-trigger="focus hover"`

Comment: I tried data-trigger="focus hover" and data-trigger="hover focus". Both are triggered on focus only, not hover.

Comment: With a quick look at the source code or documentation you can verify that this is not possible to date.

Comment: Bootstrap 3's documentation say this for data-trigger: `You may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space.` Hence it should work.

Comment: It _should_ work (now at least), but I'm getting weird results. If you're focused when you initialize the tooltip, nothing happens. If you focus and then hover in and out, the tooltip goes away (I'd expect it to stay since you're still focused).

Comment: For me, it was important to use the correct html tag. I changed to using a <button> element with "data-trigger" with "focus hover" and it began working as desired.

Answer (score 4):

`trigger` is a single-value property, so you have to fake either of both methods:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltip({trigger: 'hover'}).each(function () {
  var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('tooltip');
  $this.on('focus.tooltip', $.proxy(data.enter, data))
    .on('blur.tooltip', $.proxy(data.leave, data));
});
```

Update: Alternatively, you can use my [patch](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6040) to Twitter Bootstrap to make `trigger` a multi-value property and just set it to `hover focus`.

Comment: I tried to use the patch and still get either/or but not multiple triggers. I used your 'fake' above and it works when I don't specifiy a data-trigger. I will continue to try the patch. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried to a jsfiddle? Anyway, we should move this discussion to the [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6102).

Answer (score 4):

you can simply pass the **trigger** parameter :

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ trigger:'hover focus' });
```

[see bootstrap tooltip article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-examples)