# Bootstrap 3 tooltips visible on page load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using Bootstrap 3 tooltips, used the examples from the docs, but the problem is they show up automatically at start, when the page is loaded all the tooltips are visible!

i want them to show only on hover, what should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips on Hover & Focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572737/twitter-bootstrap-tooltips-on-hover-focus)

Comment: No duplicates in my code, I was using HTML data properties to show tooltips, i switched to showing them using JavaScript and now it works just fine, however in the docs, they you can use HTML data properties, weird! Thanks

Comment: there must be something else going on (but without your code and more info can't tell), because data properties tooltips should not do this either.

Comment: Show your code to help you quick.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("show");
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').find(".tooltip.fade.top").removeClass("in");
 });
```

or

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip("show");
    $(".tooltip.fade.top").remove();
 });
```

For Html :

> `<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is tooltip !">Hover over me</a>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you trigger bootstrap tooltip in document ready like this,

```
$('#id').tooltip('show');
```

Try to change like this

```
$('#id').tooltip();
```

Hope this will work